# Are proprietary graphic drivers worth installing?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, radeon

I installed Ubuntu on a desktop with a Radeon RX 550 graphics card and it looks like Ubuntu found the graphics card and installed an open source driver (Polaris I think?).  My question is how important is it to have the AMD Radeon proprietary drivers installed?

Everything is working good and don’t see any issues with the experience so far, but could I be getting more out of the machine with proprietary drivers?  Are proprietary drivers worth installing?

[image]

Comment: I suspect this question is very subjective (https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask); but I think acceptable, but we can only give opinions - not answers.  For me I leave it to default if I can as I've found updates easier, and it's just less hassle. I only 'change' video drivers when I'm unhappy with something (in hopes of improving it) as it takes effort, which often continues into later upgrades including to upgrading to the next version.  My 2c is if you're happy - don't touch it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience comes mostly from the Nvidia/Nouveau side of the house. And I wish to clarify that mostly this is an opinion. I leave the open source driver until I have issues. Supposedly there is better performance with gaming if you're using the proprietary driver. Where I end up moving onto the proprietary driver is when I'm doing something beyond simple usage of the graphics card. When I had two Nvidia cards in SLI, I couldn't quite get Nouveau to pull off dual monitor with each monitor driven by a different card. For machine learning, the defacto answer is to install the proprietary driver. But until you hit a use case that the OS driver can't handle, stick with what works and is better supported by your distribution.